# Calculate area of a figure based on vertices

Tags: geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How quickly we forget - basic trig. Calculate the area of a polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48993/how-quickly-we-forget-basic-trig-calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon)
>   [How to calculate the area of a polygon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66638/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon)

If I know all the vertices of a particular polygon/figure, is there a generalized method/formula to calculate the area?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to calculate the area of a polygon?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/66638/856) and [How quickly we forget - basic trig. Calculate the area of a polygon](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/48993/856).

Comment: You have to know the order of the vertices too, as otherwise there can be multiple answers

Comment: There is also [Pick's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick's_theorem).

Answer (score 6):

If you know the two-dimensional cartesian coordinates of the vertices of a (non-self-intersecting, but can be non-convex) polygon, the [Shoelace method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_Method) will find its area.  (Let me know if that article is not sufficiently clear and I'll try to explain it in more detail).