# Area of a polygon

Tags: geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How quickly we forget - basic trig. Calculate the area of a polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48993/how-quickly-we-forget-basic-trig-calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon)
>   [Calculate area of a figure based on vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102891/calculate-area-of-a-figure-based-on-vertices)

I saw a formula in a book,
$$\mathrm{area}=\frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_{i}(x_iy_{i-1}-x_{i-1}y_i)\right|.$$
Where $x_iy_i$ are the vertices of the polygon. Since it was an exercise in the book (no proof) I would very much like to see a proof, or maybe an outline? I can't come up with anything. This is no homework, I just got very curious and wanted to know.

Comment: Its very hard to figure out the answer, without knowing whether you are looking at a regular or irregular polygon . But I think that typing " derive area of polygon " in Google may fetch you lots of links. Prefer Google before moving your question to Math.SE. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_Method

Comment: @t.b. : You are exactly right , But OP could have added a reference , about the book in which he has seen the formula, in order to facilitate others .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On OP's request:

This is called the [Shoelace Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_Method) or the Shoelace method and it works as long as your polygon is simple (non-selfintersecting). There is a nice explanation on the Wikipedia page and it refers (among other things) to the article

Bart Braden, *[The Surveyor’s Area Formula](http://www.maa.org/pubs/Calc_articles/ma063.pdf)*, The College Mathematics Journal, September 1986, Volume 17, Number 4, pp. 326–337

which looks pretty nice at first glance.

---

Some related questions on this site:

1. [How quickly we forget - basic trig. Calculate the area of a polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48993/how-quickly-we-forget-basic-trig-calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon)
2. [How to calculate the area of a polygon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/66638/5363)
3. [Calculate area of a figure based on vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/102891/5363)

Comment: I salute your sincerity in keeping Community wiki, which shows that you are not interested in reputation .